# Validating that a date is greater or equal than another date, without entity

Tags: validation, date, symfony, comparison

I built a form not related to any entity.

```
class CalculatorType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('debutActivite', 'date', array(
            'label' => 'Quand avez-vous commencé votre activité ?',
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            'label_attr' => array(
                'class' => 'control-label',
            ),
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control createDatepicker',
                'placeholder' => 'dd/mm/aaaa',
            ),
            'required' => true,
        ))
        ->add('demandeAccreAccepteeDate', 'date', array(
            'label' => 'A quelle date a-t-elle été acceptée ?',
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            'label_attr' => array(
                'class' => 'control-label',
            ),
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control createDatepicker',
                'placeholder' => 'dd/mm/aaaa',
            ),
        ))
    }
}
```

And in my controller, I check if form is valid :

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new CalculatorType(), array());

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
    }
}
```

The "demandeAccreAccepteeDate" field is not required. But if it's not empty, i would like to validate that it is greater or equal to "debutActivite" field.

How can I do such a thing, knowing that I have no Calculator entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class (you don't need to persist it do the DB) to hold your date

```
namespace Your\Bundle;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContextInterface;

class Daterange
{

    /**
     * @Assert\Date()
     */
    public $debutActivite;

    /**
     * @Assert\Date()
     */
    public $demandeAccreAccepteeDate;

    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        // Do your checks
        if ( ($this->demandeAccreAccepteeDate != '') && 
               ($this->demandeAccreAccepteeDate < $this->debutActivite) ) {

            $context->addViolationAt(
                'demandeAccreAccepteeDate',
                'Date not valid. Is before debutActivite',
                array(),
                null
            );

        }

    }

}
```

Assign the date to your form

```
class CalculatorType extends AbstractType
{

    [..]

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Your\Bundle\Daterange',
        ));
    }

}
```

And in your controller create the form this way (add `use Your\Bundle\Daterange` at the beginning)

```
$form = $this->createForm(new CalculatorType(), new Daterange());
```

Comment: Do I have to store that Daterange class in Entity folder ? Or is Entity folder only for persisted classes ?

Comment: You can save it where you like.

Comment: What about best practices ? Should I save it in Entity, even if this object will never be persisted into DB ? Or in new folder called "Model" ?

Comment: This is another topic and is not related to your question. Does my solutions works ? If yes please accept it.

Comment: your solution works. I changed Daterange class for Calculator class, and added all my other fields. I am now doing all my custom validation into this validate() method. Thank you.